# Mongoose - Update object array with multiple objects

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a document that contains an array of line items e.g sku, description etc and i need to append a new field to it from a seperate source.  This source containts the sku for matching and a second field [lineItemId].  What's the best way to update this all at once?  I'd like to do it with a direct update but not sure if i need to pull the data into node, map in the lineItemId and the push the update back.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Collection Object in MDB

```
{
   _id: ....
   orderId: 1
   lineItems: [{
      sku: "sku1",
      description: "item description"
   },
   {
      sku: "sku2",
      description: "item description"
   }]
}
```

Second Source

```
[{
   sku: "sku1",
   lineItemId: "1234"
},
{
   sku: "sku2",
   lineItemId: "5678"
}
]
```

Desired Result

```
{
   _id: ....
   orderId: 1
   lineItems: [{
      sku: "sku1",
      description: "item description",
      lineItemId: "1234"
   },
   {
      sku: "sku2",
      description: "item description",
      lineItemId: "5678"
   }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use UPSERT Method**

```
document.findOneAndUpdate({
    orderId: 1
}, { description: "item description" }, { upsert: true });
```